# Listing variable name, label, and all value labels in one line

Tags: label, stata, stata-macros

I want to list a variable's name, label, as well as all values and value labels on one line, for each variable in the dataset.

For example:

```
foreign, Car type, 0 Domestic 1 Foreign
```

I managed to write some code to do this, but it only shows value labels that are used in the dataset:

```
sysuse auto, clear

foreach var of varlist * {
    local _check: val l `var'
    if `"`_check'"' != "" {
        quietly fre `var'
        di "`var'" char(44) `"`: var label `var' '"' char(44) as result r(lab_valid)
        continue    
        }
    else{
        di "`var'" char(44) `"`: var label `var' '"'    
        continue
        }
}
```

Here the *community-contributed* command `fre` would only include `0 Domestic`, if the data did not include `1 Foreign`.

There are easier ways to show value labels, but all show them on different lines.

Comment: See `help limits` for the limits on number and length and value labels, which could singly or jointly overwhelm a single line. You're evidently not thinking that that could bite _you_.

Answer (score 0):

Using the option `include` in `fre` solves the problem of wanting to list all value labels one line, even those that aren't used in the data.

For example:

```
foreach var of varlist * {  
    local _check: val l `var'
    if `"`_check'"' != "" {
        quietly fre `var', include
        di "`var'" char(44) `"`: var label `var' '"' char(44) as result r(lab_valid)
        continue    
        }
    else{
        di "`var'" char(44) `"`: var label `var' '"'    
        continue
        }
}
```